# How to make files unaccesable for User (Browser) on Apache server?

Tags: php, apache

I have a webside running on Apache and I want to make some files acceseble only via php. For example: I have a file "secret.html" and I don't want to be user able to do `www.example.com/secret.html` but he could do `www.exapmle.com/verify.php`, it would check if he can view it and then the php would do `include "secret.html";` and it would be shown.

Comment: You have to convert secret.html to secret.php and check for $_SESSION in starting of this file.

Comment: @BSB or set up the server to process html files as php

Comment: Html files can not be processed as php as HTML is client side and PHP is server side language.  HTML files are processed by browser and PHP files by server.

Comment: @BSB You are misinformed, you can easily allow htm, html, etc files to process PHP using .htaccess, though this is not default behavior

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes it is possible. But in that case you will not be able to show it again after .php file which is requirement in this question.

Comment: @BSB I'm sorry, I'm not really following your last comment, not sure what you mean by "show it again". If I'm wrong please let me know, I love to learn about this stuff

Comment: include secret.html; is not possible in verify.php, You need to save secret.html as secret.php to include. Also verification can not be done in xxxx.html file as HTML is client side language. ( As per question requirement )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151618/discussion-between-bsb-and-grumpycrouton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at least 2 ways to do what you want.

### By htaccess

Add a special rule that deny access to the "secret" file. In order to simplify, you can just create a "secret" directory and then place into it every secret files. Then, create a .htaccess file in this directory that contains :

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all
```

Finally, update "verify.php" and use `include` for php file :

```
include "secret/secret.php";
```

or `readfile`for html file :

```
readfile("secret/secret.html");
```

### By VirtualHost

This one is trickiest.
What you can do is to customize a little bit your vhost in your Apache settings.
Let's say you have 2 folders at the root of your website :

- "secret" will contains the files you don't want to be accessible by browsers
- "web" will contains your "verifiy.php" file

Then, change your Apache VirtualHost setting "DocumentRoot" to point to the "web" directory.
Finally, update "verify.php" and use `include` for php file :

```
include "../secret/secret.php";
```

or `readfile`for html file :

```
readfile("../secret/secret.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file in your directory.

```
//set deny all to all request which contain .html extension.
<Files *.html>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
//set allow to all .php file.
<Files *.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

in your verify.php file include your .html file

```
include "path/secret.html";
```

I hope it will be helpful.